# How can I use commander (npm) with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following code on my app:

```
import commander = require('commander');

commander
  .option('-u, --user [user]', 'user code')
  .option('-p, --pass [pass]', 'pass code')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

Then I try to access:

```
commander.user
```

But I get an error (commander.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped):

```
user does not exist on type IExportedCommand
```

I tried adding this

```
interface IExportedCommand {
  user: string;
  pass: string;
}
```

But I still get the error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file `commander-expansion.d.ts` with the following :

```
declare namespace commander {
    interface IExportedCommand extends ICommand {
        user: string; 
        pass: string;
    }
}
```

## Tip

Because I did something like this recently, recommend `--auth user:password`. Saves you dealing with user missing username or password. But prevents using `:` as a password property

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

More : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/master/src/server/commandLine.ts#L24

Answer (score 10):

You can also do:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/commander
```

EDIT: Commander now includes its own TypeScript typings, so this should no longer be necessary.

Comment: I feel this is a better answer as it leveraged existing typings built by the open source community. I assume the end goal of the user is to "use the typing from typescript", not just to prevent compiler errors.

Comment: Just as a note Commander now ships with its own types, no need anymore to install `@types/commander`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the Typescript interface within the same file.

```
interface InterfaceCLI extends commander.ICommand {
  user?: string
  password?: string
}
```

After you can define this interface to a variable after running the `program.parse` function.

```
const cli: InterfaceCLI = program.parse(process.argv)
console.log(cli.user, cli.password)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old but I had a lot of trouble finding help with it.  I solved it, but I am not yet fluent in either Typescript or JavaScript, and would like some feedback.

After reading the answers above I could not figure out where the type **ICommand** was located.   However I did find a type name **Command**.

Furthermore the various snippets use inconsistent variable names which made them difficult to decipher.

So I played around a while and came up with this complete example.  The entire app is in one file:

```
import commander = require('commander');

interface InterfaceCLI extends commander.Command {
    user?: string
    password?: string
}
class Startup {
    public static main(): number {
        const cli: InterfaceCLI = commander
            .option('-u, --user [user]', 'user id')
            .option('-p, --password [password]', 'user\'s password')
            .parse(process.argv);
        console.log(cli.user, cli.password);

        return 0;
    }
}

Startup.main();
```

Dependencies: `install commander@2.16.0 --save`

Please let me know what you think of this solution as I intend to use it as the starting point of a production command line application.